# Unable to read payment amount through python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I want to read amounts $0.00, $749, etc., but it looks like none of the element attribute properties are working.

I have tried the following already:

```
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.RadioButton[@index='0']").text()
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.RadioButton[@index='0']").get_text()
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.RadioButton[@index='0']").get_attr_name()
```

any many more but still to retrieve any value.

Comment: Does `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.RadioButton[@index='0']")` by itself return a webdriver element?

Comment: it returns <appium.webdriver.webelement.WebElement (session="76b7021c-415d-4705-9321-bc6b89c8bae3", element="37"

Comment: And what happens when you call `.text()`? Does it throw an error, or return an empty string?